# How do I write a command in vim to run multiple commands?

Tags: vim

I've written some commands that perform common functions by placing the following in my `.vimrc` files:

```
command! FixWhitespace %s/ \+$//g
command! FixCommas %s/,\S\@=/, /g
```

Now I'd like to create a 3rd command that runs both of these, but the following doesn't work:

```
command! Fix FixWhitespace|FixCommas
```

When I run `:Fix` from within `vim` I get the following message:

> E488: Trailing characters: FixWhitespace|FixCommas

I'm not sure how this error message relates to what I've done, but I'm obviously not doing something right!

I'm using Vim 7.4.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to tell vim using `command! -bar` that a command can be followed by another command with the pipe symbol `|`:

```
command! -bar FixWhitespace %s/\s\+$//e
command! FixCommas %s/,\S\@=/, /ge
```

Now this is OK:

```
command! Fix FixWhitespace|FixCommas
```

but this isn't:

```
command! Fix FixCommas|FixWhitespace
```

See `:h command-bar` for more details.

The error message `E488: Trailing characters: FixWhitespace|FixCommas` is vim's way of telling you that it didn't expect anything following the `FixWhitespace` command. See `:h E488`.

---

As an aside, your `FixWhitespace` command doesn't need the `g` flag since the pattern can match at most once on each line. I'd also set the `e` flag to suppress the annoying error message. See `:h s_flags`.